# How to design document collections not like SQL, given the 2MB limit?

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb, document-database

Here's the issue I'm having in moving from SQL to a document db with a 2MB limit on documents. Suppose I have an  entities that looks like this

```
unit
   id
   item[]

item
   id
   name
```

If `item[]` can be arbitrary length (as is usually the case), then I can't store the `unit` in its literal representation because there's a chance that its size could exceed 2MB. What I think I have to do in such a case is convert this structure to

```
unit
   id

item
   id
   unitId
   name
```

and then need to perform "joins," which feels too much like SQL (Hence, what's the point of using no-SQL?).

Comment: If you need relations enforced by the database, you will probably need a *relational* database :)

Comment: "what's the point of using no-SQL?" - exactly. Modern relational databases can handle most tasks you throw at them. Why abandon a perfectly working tool? :shrug:

Answer (score -3):

this is more of a architecture question than of a development one, but here's the deal: 
Plan your data based on 3 levels, where

- level one, represents micro data, such as a person and his two addresses.
- The level 2 represents mid-sized lists, such as all the sales a store performed on a single day
- level 3 are the huge lists with billions of itens

the idea is that for cases 1 and 2 you can very much store that info nested on the entity, without any issues on a foreseeable future (remember that 2MB doc is a very long document, with over 2 million chars) and this means no joins! on a heavily used system, this can mean huge savings!

I'd suggest that you study your data, plan it's behavior and see if you do need to break it apart